# When the cursor is moved over the face of a person, the name of the person is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

`I have a photo with several people on a website (made with php) and would like to obtain the following: when the cursor is moved over the face of a person, the name of the person is displayed at the bottom of the photo. After a lot of search, I found some code on another website that was close to what I wanted and after I changed a few things I got it to do (mostly) what I want but I really do not understand much of it and I am convinced there must be a simpler way to do it. The code is copied below.

```
<style>
    .imageMapContainer{
      position: relative;
    }
    .imageMapZone{
      position: absolute;
    }
    .namezone{
      Font-size: 1.4em;
      min-height: 1.6em;
    }</style>
<script>
```

```
var co=
co+='<div class="imageMapContainer">';
           co+='<img  width="700" src ="/img/equipe.jpg"/></div>';
           co+= '<div class="namezone"></div>';
data = {
  Clara: {
    left: 284,
    top: 38,
    width: 121,
    height: 191
  },
  Sylvie: {
    left: 412,
    top: 9,
    width: 121,
    height: 191
  },
  Steeve: {
    left: 498,
    top: 79,
    width: 208,
    height: 191
  },
  Jacques: {
    left: 56,
    top: 179,
    width: 157,
    height: 191
  },
  Julie: {
    left: 213,
    top: 178,
    width: 106,
    height: 178
  },
  Amélie: {
    left: 300,
    top: 319,
    width: 139,
    height: 211
  },
  Robert: {
    left: 456,
    top: 282,
    width: 182,
    height: 229
  }
};

let names = Object.keys(data);
names.forEach((n) => {
  let zone = $("<div>");
  zone
    .addClass("imageMapZone")
    .css(data[n])
    .hover(
      function () {
        $(".namezone").text(n);
      },
      function () {
        $(".namezone").text("");
      }
    );
  $(".imageMapContainer").append(zone);
});
        
</script>
```

why does this code not work`

Comment: Sorry, but first you said you copied code and modified it and it does mostly what you want. So at the bottom you say "why does this code not work" If you are asking why it does not do exactly as you want, you will FIRST have to tell us wht you want it to do and then in what way this code falls short

Comment: Explain what doesn't work. Do the divs get created? Do they have the right CSS but they don't appear at the right position? Do they appear at the right position but the hover behaviour doesn't work?

Comment: `var co=` equals what? do you mean `var co=''`? where is the html?

Comment: Also your first item in `data` is not valid JS syntax: The key has a space and is not enclosed in quotes, and the values are neither valid number or string literals.

Answer (score 1):

**Without any JavaScript**

An [image map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map) is an html element that allows you to divide an image into multiple [areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area).  Areas can be rectangles, circles, or complex polygon shapes. Each area has its own hover and touch events and may also be used as a link to another page.

[image]

Creating area coordinates manually is a cumbersome task and prone to mistakes. Fortunately, there are many free online tools that allow you to upload an image and create coordinates. For example, [imagemap.org](https://imagemap.org/) and [image-map.net](https://www.image-map.net/).

This example uses an image with multiple people and each person has been mapped to an area. We can then add some css to make each person's name appear when the mouse hovers over their face. The key parts are adding the pseudo-element [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before) and then setting the text to display using `content: attr(title)`

```
area:hover:before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 75%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: white;
}
```

**Comment**

Image maps should be used sparingly as they are time consuming to maintain. For example, a new image and map would need to be created each time there is a staff change.

**Snippet**

Open the snippet to view the complete code. The snippet places the text at the top so that it is visible without scrolling. However, the position can be set anywhere within the image by adjusting the css.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
.staff {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

area:hover:before {
  content: attr(title);
  position: absolute;
  top: 5%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="staff">

<img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MpkPRfrf/people.jpg" usemap="#image-map">

<map name="image-map">
    <area title="Clara" coords="105,137,44" shape="circle">
    <area title="Jacques" coords="85,3,154,87" shape="rect">
    <area title="Robert" coords="301,110,38" shape="circle">
    <area title="Julie" 
      coords="245,100,205,113,183,170,270,182,261,119" shape="poly">
    <area title="Amélie" 
      coords="214,11,186,52,209,99,241,90,258,97,276,62,271,21" shape="poly">
</map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say definitively without knowing exactly what errors you're getting. However, if you posted the code exactly as it's written, here's what stands out:

- `var co=`

  - This line is invalid. What does `co` equal?
  - Maybe initialize it to an empty string: `var co = "";`
- `Chraibi Mariam: {`

  - This line is invalid. Object property names cannot have spaces without enclosing them in quotes.
  - Use this instead: `"Chraibi Mariam": {`

Comment: As I mentioned above, the values in the "Chraibi Mariam" item are not valid literals either. They should probably be numbers (ie without px").
I also suspect the code in "co" isn't rendered as HTML...
There are a lot of issues, but it's hard to help because we can't really tell what OP even understands of the code they posted.